# Redirecting to same page with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

From my .htaccess  file:

```
RewriteRule ^showPAGE.php page [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^page showPAGE.php [NC,L]
```

I want users going to url `domain.com/showPAGE.php` to be redirected to `domain.com/page` . 
When `domain.com/page` is being entered, I want it to show the content of the file `showPAGE.php`.
Is that possible to do?
The above results an infinite redirection loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do something that's **very** tricky. The problem is that, by design, the `RedirectRule` directive always triggers again the complete set of rules. You can only get out of the loop when you obtain a final URL that does not match any of the rules and that's the tricky part since you are reusing the `showPAGE.php` name.

My best attempt so far involves adding a fake hidden string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/showPAGE\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^internal
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/page [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^page$ showPAGE.php?internal [NC,L]
```

It works but it's not pleasant. Definitively, it's easier to handle the redirection from with PHP or to simply pick another name.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect from `showPAGE.php` to `page` needs to have [L] so that it will stop processing and redirect at once, rather than going on and applying other rules (which at once map it back to showPAGE.php). Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^showPAGE.php page [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page showPAGE.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I am still getting "This webpage has a redirect loop." :/

Comment: I've actually tried it out now, trying different combinations of `RewriteRule`, putting in some `RewriteCond` s, using `Alias` and `Redirect`, all to no avail... I think I'm stuck. Have you tried handling the showPAGE.php -> page redirect inside showPAGE.php?

Comment: Chris, first of all thanks for the effort! :)  I can do it inside the PHP page, and I can also rename it. Just wondered if there is a short (more convenient and efficient) way to do it. I will just rename the file. Thanks again!

Comment: Renaming the page never occurred to me! :-/